# Store a JSON object passed as a prop and how to access its values

Tags: json, reactjs, react-router

so in React, I have a json object that represents a soccer league with data that looks like this:

```
        {
            "league_id": 1,
            "name": "World Cup",
            "type": "Cup",
            "country": "World",
            "country_code": null,
            "season": 2018,  
        }
```

I pass this as a prop to React Router Link like so:

```
<Link className="linktext" to={{
     pathname: '/Leagues/' + {nameofLeague},
     state: {
         league: this.props.league
     }
     }}>
</Link>
```

And I want to print some of the values for keys, like "name" and "country" of the json object that I passed to the file below:

```
class LeagueInstancePage extends Component {
    state = {
        league: null
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        const {path} = this.props.match.params

        ***this is the json object and is passed successfully***
        const {league} = this.props.location.state

        console.log(path)
        console.lot(league)

        this.setState({league: this.props.location.state})
    }


render() {    
    return (
       <h3>League: {this.state.league.name} </h3></Row>
    );

   }
}
export default LeagueInstancePage;
```

The console log outputs work and is able to print the object like so:

[image]

**The Problem:**

I'm unable to access the values of the object in the h3 tag in the render() of the file. Any ideas?

Comment: I looks like maybe the render is occurring once before the state is being set, and your error may be occurring there (but you didn't elaborate on how you are unable to access the value, what specific errors were occurring). However, you should be able to just access the value from the props directly (unless you want to ignore the prop value after the componentDidMount).

Comment: @GarrettMotzner is right, by the time your component renders this.state.league is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `render` can be called (an indeterminate number of times) *before* the first commit to the screen, i.e. when the component actually mounts.

[image]

As you can see here, `render` is called during the "render phase", much earlier than `componentDidMount` in the "commit phase".

Your initial state is null though, so this is why you can't access it. The common pattern to solve for this is react [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

```
class LeagueInstancePage extends Component {
    state = {
        league: null
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        const {path} = this.props.match.params

        const {league} = this.props.location.state

        console.log(path)
        console.lot(league)

        this.setState({league: this.props.location.state})
    }

render() {
    const { league: { name } } = this.state;    
    return name ? (
      <Row>
        <h3>League: {name} </h3>
      </Row>
    ) : null;
  }
}

export default LeagueInstancePage;
```

**Note:** It is also a common anti-pattern to duplicate passed props *in* component state. In your case, you can directly access the `props.location.state.league.name`, but should still use the appropriate object property access guards to defend against "access ... of undefined.." errors in the case a user indirectly navigates to the page rendering this component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering like so:

```
<h3>League: {this.state.league? this.state.league.name: "Loading.."} </h3></Row>
```

Or you can hide the whole line to avoid seeing "League:Loading..." on your screen.

When the state updates, the component is rerendered and it will correctly display the field.